# Image does not display with directory but displays with the image code

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, svg

Chrome does not display my `.svg` image but displays once the code of the image is inserted along with html.

For example (without image code)

[image]

with image code
[image]

Why does this happen and what is the cause of it?

Comment: Add proper path of the image in the first image code, it should work. It seems like its not a valid path.

Comment: path is good. Other images work fine and only .svg type are not being displayed.

Comment: Hi I think this thread from SO can fix your problem :)
[SVG Won't Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338648/svg-wont-display)

Answer (score 1):

these are 2 different possible solutions 
1) be sure that your path is correct
2) try removing that height and write `style="height:20px;"`

Comment: Path is correct and changing the height did not work.

Comment: well. can you provide the possible causes of this issue.

Comment: can you post me all the code where you insert the img?

Comment: because i use chrome, too, and i assure you that it displays the svg. So the problem may be with your code

Comment: Mozilla displays the image without any changes in the code.