# SVGs not displaying Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, svg

I am trying to figure out why my **SVG icons are not displaying in Chrome**. I am calling the `svg` with a standard `<image src=... />`, and **I am able to see the image in dev tools** (dev tools) and by visiting the direct path. I am also able to see the svgs in any other browser.

I've tried:

- Saving the svg in Illustrator with "Embed" instead of "Link" : [Chrome not rendering SVG referenced via <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/chrome-not-rendering-svg-referenced-via-img-tag)
- Explicitly registering SVG mime type
- Using Rails' `<%= image_tag %>` ERB helper
- Using SVG export settings suggested by Adobe: http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/09/exporting-svg-illustrator.html

Here is my view:

```
<a class="collapsed accordion-box">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <img class="collapse-bullet" src="<%= asset_path 'blue-right-bullet.svg' %>"/>
  </div>
</a>
```

#### Edit:

Found that other random SVGs show up fine:

- This one is working: https://goo.gl/Hcs7Sx (white on white)
- This one does not: https://goo.gl/WGkY3r

Both are called with `<img src="..."/>` via  the `<%= image_tag %>` helper

Comment: Is your SVG vector only?

Comment: @MichaelDeSilva yep, vector only.

Comment: Try to use an absolute path in your source, and see how that works

Comment: Well these SVGs display fine in Chrome as standaklone SVGs.  So you are probably going to have to make a sample fiddle or page that shows the problem.

Comment: As a last ditch effort, try this https://github.com/jamesmartin/inline_svg I have however been able to get SVGs to also render as the background image via CSS using `image-url`.

Comment: I had the same problem. How did you export your svg? Initially I used Photoshop but when I tried exporting the same svg in Illustrator, then it worked.

Comment: @sammiepls Yep! its been two years, but IFRC exporting I ended up redrawing this asset myself in Ai and it worked.