# SVG logo not showing in Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, svg

I am trying use an svg image for my logo. It is showing up fine in Firefox but it won't show in Chrome. The file path is correct but even when I inspect element the thumbnail shows as empty.

http://benefacto.org/category/employee-engagement-mini-series/

```
 <a href="/" class="home-logo">Logo</a>

.home-logo {

background: url('/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/home-logo.svg');
background-size: 400px 64px;
text-indent: -9999px;
height: 64px;
width: 400px;
display: block;
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: More answer to your solution is discussed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/chrome-not-rendering-svg-referenced-via-img-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svg file only contains a base64 encoded png. So it's not a 'real' svg. 
Include the png directly in your css.

```
background-image: url('data:img/png;base64,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');
```

Comment: Thanks Nico. That solves it. Is there any real advantage of this over using a large png and resizing it using css?

Comment: Not really. If I were you I would convert it to a png and reference it in an image tag.

Comment: Thanks Nico. Really appreciate your help.