# Chrome not rendering SVGZ from local file but does render SVGZ from server

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have saved a complete HTML page from a server using Chrome.

When I load the local file again in Chrome, the SVGZ images do not render and instead shows a broken image icon.

- Double checking the file and loading again from the original server, I find that the SVGZ loads just fine
- If I load just the local image file on its own, I get prompted to save the image
- If I edit the local image filename extension to .SVG, and load on its own, it renders just fine
- If I then edit the HTML file to refer to the renamed file with the .SVG extension, then the entire page and image all loads correctly

---

I know this is not strictly a programming issue, but in doing a lot of searching, I have found more closely related answers here on StackOverflow than on say AskUbuntu.

This answer provides the best clue I have found thus far:

[Chrome not rendering SVG referenced via <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/chrome-not-rendering-svg-referenced-via-img-tag)

> I came here because I had a similar problem, the image was not being
>   rendered. What I found out was that the content type header of my
>   testing server wasn't correct. I fixed it by adding the following to
>   my .htaccess file:
>
> ```
> AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
> AddEncoding gzip svgz
> ```

So I am *guessing* that the problem lies somewhere with:

- when loaded from the server, the content type is correctly specified
- when loaded from my local file, the content type is NOT correctly specified

---

Is there any way to resolve this ?

Can I "mimic" the .htaccess mime type and encoding by changing a Chrome setting ?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a test HTML file with an `<img>` that loads a .svgz file. It worked okay (Chrome on Win7).

Check that your .svgz file is actually a gzipped SVG file, and not something else. For instance I suspect that it is actually a normal SVG file but with a ".svgz" extension.  That will fail in the way you describe.

Comment: Thanks ... that makes sense. If I open the **.svgz** file in a vanilla text editor, it is indeed plain text ... no compression there. So I am guessing that the file on the server is **.svgz** and it gets uncompressed by the browser as the page loads. Then when I save the page, the now _uncompressed_ **.svg** file is saved with the **.svgz** extension. Then, on reopening of the local .html page, the incorrect extension name causes the browser to spit the dummy.

Comment: Just reporting the results from an additional test: Firefox exhibits the same behaviour ... so it's not just a Chrome issue.

Comment: One last question - for my understanding: Would this "break" all locally saved web pages where **.svgz** files are used ? Is this typical a typical behaviour problem using that image format ?

Comment: [ I did try to mark your answer as my accepted solution to my question but my rep is too low. Same situation with an up-vote. Manual thanks here :-) ]

Comment: Yes. What you suspected is also what I assumed was happening.  Any site that precompresses it's SVG files would have this problem. I suspect that not many do.  This is first time I have seen this problem reported here.

Comment: Reported Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=654686