# <object type="image/svg+xml"> rendering very inconsistent/random in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, object, svg

When I try to show .svg files as an image, Chrome would not show it when I tried to write it like this:
`<img src='/images/shape.svg'>`

I found that .svg is often not rendered well by Google Chrome, but you could use `<object>` instead ([found that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/chrome-not-rendering-svg-referenced-via-img-tag)).
Now the `<object>`-tag is working for me on all cases and pages, but this one. I don't know why, but something makes my images/objects shift up and down inside its own container. As you can see on this inspector here.

!! the `<svg>` and the `<object>` on the right image are the same height in the inspector
[image: inspector]

UPDATE: also, it is not always the right one that renders and the rest not. It is literally completely random. Sometimes 1 and 4 render correct, sometimes only 3, sometimes none, ...

I have put my code in this [fiddle](https://codepen.io/nclsvh/pen/yzBrBy)
Thanks for any help on this

Comment: Your pen doesn't reproduce the described behavior for me, even when the protocol issue is resolved. Can you include a link to the real svg file? Also, is there really only an `<image>` in this svg? Why wrap it in svg?

Comment: I will try to reproduce the error in Codepen or somewhere else, later today. Well, when I wrap it in `<img>`tag it won't show at all in Chrome..

Comment: While trying to reproduce it in JSFiddle I found out it was fixed when adding a height in px for the `<object>`..  Thanks anyway for the reply