# Laravel 5.6 displaying an svg icon in my blade view not working

Tags: php, laravel, svg

I have an icon in this location stored: `public/icons/list.svg` and in my blade I try to display the icon like this:

```
{{ Html::image('icons/list.svg', 'list') }}
```

This results into this in my html page:

```
<img src="https://url.dev/icons/list.svg" alt="list">
```

But this unfortunately doesn't work it displays as if the file can not be found.
(this works great for .png or .jpg files)

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52226069/1228951

Comment: @Anders I don't find that "xlink:href..."

Comment: @Michael, do you use apache as server?

Comment: @niklaz yes I do use apache

Comment: @Michael, check my answer

Comment: To detect if is a problem with the svg file or the server try load a working svg image first like https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/conform/smiley.svg, second open your svg image in browser (see if you can view it), check directory and file permissions, check your server for allowed files type extensions

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Apache doesn't recognize media type for svg, so try adding in your .htaccess:

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
```

Comment: I don't have a .htaccess

Comment: @Michael, add one in your public directory

Comment: @Michael, did you check permissions for 'icons' directory?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it doesn't work for me either and I've used the source code of the svg image

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
    .
    .
    .
</svg>
```

to get the source code of svg, just open the svg in a browser and view the source

Comment: You can also copy the svg straight out of illustrator, When you paste it into the codes it just pastes the complete svg code.