# React/Ionic: Not rendering SVG via <img/> tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, svg

I seem to be facing an issue with loading SVG's within my React/Ionic App.  I am getting the weather via OpenWeatherMap and accessing which icon to use via this `weather?.weather[0].icon` I am using the following icon pack https://github.com/basmilius/weather-icons but when I insert the above it does not render the SVG icons I am using it like
`` <img src={`../images/${weather?.weather[0].icon}.svg`}/> `` but it keeps showing it like the image is missing.

The images are in the images directory which has the same root directory as this page

```
Page is in src/pages
Image is in src/images
```

Anyone have any tips on why this may be?

A sample SVG from the pack is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><g><circle cx="32" cy="32" r="11.64" fill="#f4a71d"/><path fill="none" stroke="#f4a71d" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3" d="M32 15.71V9.5M32 54.5v-6.21M43.52 20.48l4.39-4.39M16.09 47.91l4.39-4.39M20.48 20.48l-4.39-4.39M47.91 47.91l-4.39-4.39M15.71 32H9.5M54.5 32h-6.21"/><animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="45s" from="0 32 32" repeatCount="indefinite" to="360 32 32" type="rotate"/></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

You need to change the way you are importing the images:

**1. import an image from the same source directory:**

```
import Img from "/path/to/image.svg"

<img src={Img}/>
```

**2. import an image from the public folder:**

```
<img src="/path/to/image.svg"/>
```

#### Solution:

If you want to import images dynamically and you are using `Webpack`, you can use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext):

```
const svgDir = require.context("!@svgr/webpack!../images");
```

then:

```
<img src={svgDir(`./${weather?.weather[0].icon}.svg`)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick tip on how to fix this can be found here --> https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/svg-css-background-image-not-showing-in-chrome/

I believe the problem is with the SVG itself.
If you open the SVG in the browser and inspect the code you will see the svg contains just a base64 encoded PNG
http://staging.flagstaff.ab.ca/templates/base/images/page-bg.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1922" height="432" viewBox="0 0 1922 432">
  <image id="Swoosh" width="1922" height="432" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,=====LONG BASE 64 ENCODE HERE=====" >
</svg>
```

Maybe some browsers/OS have problems in rendering the svg in this way.

Since it is not a real SVG just convert it in PNG and use the png instead.
Or include the base64 directly in your css by changing

```
background-image: url('your-file.svg');
with

background-image: url('data:img/png;base64,=====LONG BASE 6
```

So...

```
xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,
```

to:

```
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,
```

Check this response --> [Chrome not rendering SVG referenced via <img> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/chrome-not-rendering-svg-referenced-via-img-element)