# HTML issue with svg fragmenting on chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, laravel-blade

I have a SVG background for my website and it is causing flickering, I have opened it both in edge and firefox and it is only a chrome issue. It will happen randomly even if I have just loaded the website and not moving mouse/ scrolling.

I have tried adding backface visibility to hidden as I seen this may fix the issue but it has not, I also placed an img tag in the div and set the image src to the svg but this also did not work. I feel like it has something to do with the animations on the svg but unsure on how to fix this issue.

Comment: So your car doesn't drive and now you _describe_ a picture of your car to us... Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using CSS to set the background image:
Use media queries to render a raster(PNG) version of the image on chrome only.

However if that's not feasible you could try the following answer, supposedly you can edit your SVG file such that it will render in chrome.

[Chrome not rendering SVG referenced via <img> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/chrome-not-rendering-svg-referenced-via-img-element)